# If-Else loop output

Tags: php, if-statement, printing

```
<?php
$x = 1;
if ($x == 2)
    print "hi" ;
else if($x = 2)
    print $x;
else
    print "how are u";
?>
```

Apologies for this basic question as I am a beginner at php.

I was expecting the else statement to be executed and print "how are u", but it executed the elseif statement and printed '2' instead. May I ask why does $x become assigned to 2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are **SETTING** `x=2` in your `else if` --> `else if($x = 2)` --  This would be more appropriate .. Check for absolute `===` ..  Then check for truthy `==` .. IE

```
<?php
$x = 1;
if ($x === 2)
    print "hi" ;
else if($x == 2)
    print $x;
else
    print "how are u";
?>
```

Conversely ..  You can play with truthy vs absolute by comparing an integer to string too ..  Like:

```
<?php
$x = 2;
if ($x === 2)                      // Will return true
    print "Is absolute integer" ;
else if($x == 2)                   // Will return true
    print "Is truthy integer";
else if($x === '2')                // Will return false
    print "Is absolute string";
else if($x == '2')                 // Will return true
    print "Is truthy string";
else
    print "how are u";
?>
```

Which will never reach the else .. But you can see how operators can make or break a program ..

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$x = 1;
if ($x == 2)
    print "hi" ;
else if($x = 2) /* you assign $x 2  and it's true  */
    print $x;
else
    print "how are u";
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: i explain in code with comment but you right too

Answer (score 0):

In the elseif you are asigning the number 2 to $x which will always return true. Because of that it will never go to the else block.
Dont use = when doing comparisons but == or  ===.

```
   <?php
   $x = 1;
   if ($x == 2)
       print "hi" ;
   else if($x == 2)
       print $x;
   else
       print "how are u";
   ?>
```

this is the right way to do it. Also it doesnt make sense to check both in if and elseif that $x == 2 since it will never execute the elseif block.
Let me try to explain it better, if you do:

```
if ($x = 2)
```

thats will assign 2 to $x and this is then the same as:

```
if ($x)
```

since the $x now holds the number 2 this is also the same as:

```
if (2)
```

this is always true so it will never go to further checks no matter what the number is.

Comment: Your answer negates the need for an `else if`

Comment: as i clarified in the comments the elseif doesnt make sense either way. i just explained why.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `=` is assignment operator not comparison like `==`. That is why `$x` is assigned value 2 and the else if condition is met and executed.